# What ud stands for in PHP query

Tags: php

I'm having trouble understanding the "ud" in this query. Actually this code is working. I already researched the manual etc.. I don't know if I'm correct or wrong but I just want a clear understanding of my thoughts so that I can apprehend my conclusion about his ud in this query. Thanks a lot..

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT ud.*  FROM user ud  WHERE ud.status = 'Y'  ORDER BY ud.id ASC");
```

Comment: That's an alias for the table called `user`. It' from the MySQL part, not PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is a concept of ALIAS in sql, by using which we can
>   provide an ALIAS i.e. additional name to table name or to column name
>   to make the name shorter or meaningful.

[Read here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm)